# Is ffmpeg-php important to run ffmpeg in php?

Tags: ffmpeg, php

I installed ffmpeg (not ffmpeg-php)

Now can I run a command like this?:

```
exect('ffmpeg -i begin.mp4 end.ogg');
```

My server provider told me  I couldn't run this command in php because of ffmpeg-php!
But I think it's wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ffmpeg-php is used to programmatically retrieve information and perform various tasks on files. All you are doing with an `exec(...)` is calling an external binary. As long as you have ffmpeg (not the php extension) installed, you can `exec()` it.

Also see [FFmpeg Wiki: Using FFmpeg from PHP scripts](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20FFmpeg%20from%20PHP%20scripts).

Answer (score 0):

Your service provider told you this because it's unlikely they allow your PHP scripts to run an external file, or a limited number of them.  This is very common in a shared hosting environment.